# Flipping two different images and stopping on hover

Tags: html, css

The idea is to create an infinite animation on CSS that will show two sides of a card spinning all the time and to stop the animation on hover, revealing only the front and increasing the size 20% with a link to another section.

I am able to flip and grow to the second image on hover, but I seem to be unable to replace the action on a Keyframe animation.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.panel {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: CardFlip 5s infinite;
}
.front {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300/red');

}
.back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);  
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);  
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300/blue');

}
.panel:hover .front {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel:hover .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -moz-transform:  scale(1.2,1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

@-webkit-keyframes CardFlip {
  0%   { 
position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -moz-transform:  scale(1.2,1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
  100% { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>        
<br>    
<div class="panel">
    <div class="front card">
    </div>
    <div class="back card">  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `z-index` property will not be applied to selectors unless you include the `position` property as well.

Comment: (Thank you for answering)
By setting the position property as:

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 

Do I need to modify it?

Comment: All I mean is, you have several selectors that include `z-index` value declarations. These selectors also need to **all** include a `position` declaration, whether it be `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`, in order for the `z-index` to work.

Comment: You mean to use:
.back {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);   ....

Comment: I added the position property everywhere I have the Z-index and added the @keyframes... now I see only half the animation... any suggestion?

Also I added on:
.card {
 -webkit-animation: CardFlip 2s linear infinite; 
and on:
@-webkit-keyframes CardFlip {
 from {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 to {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);

 }

Also.. how can I continue commenting with such a small amount of characters?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it as a solution (hence the comments), I am merely saying that if you want your `z-index` properties to actually do anything, then you need to add `position` to those elements as well.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle so we can see your progress so far.

Comment: is this sort of what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/3R6KJ/

Comment: Yes haxxxton, that's more like it...
Except that the first part of the animation is backwards..
But I believe I can fix it.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `backface-visibility: hidden;` only to front card.

If you need your animation to have infinite look, you have to have similar 0% and 100% points.

Also, you had missed `transform-style: preserve-3d;` property.

Also, I've added one more container to avoid animation on cards. I think it's more semantic.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/2zrk7/

**Update**

If we add `perspective: 1000` to the main container, we'll get real 3d effect. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/2zrk7/1/

**Update 2**

And if we need only **left-to-right** flipping we can set `360deg` instead of `0deg` into 100% point in the animation. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/2zrk7/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go with the update 2!

Now I will try showing and increasing the size of each image on hover, instead of showing only the front... I mean, if I hover on the front to show the front, and if I hover on the back to show the back...

Thank you for all your help
Guys you are amazing!

Comment: Ah, ok. Let me know if you get trouble with this.

Comment: I have not been able to make this work on IExplorer or Firefox, any ideas?